# How Can I pass two variable in Ajax URL to codeigniter controller?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on a School Management system. I am just creating fetch student details by their class and section. I use ajax + codeigniter controller but I am unable to pass two variable in ajax call to perform 2 parameter search.

**My Ajax Code**

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#example').DataTable({
                        'paging': true,
                        'searching': true,
                        'ordering': true,
                        'autoWidth': false
                    });
                    $('#student').click(function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var xclass = $('.sclass').val();
                        var section = $('.section').val();

                        //
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Admission/fetchStudent/",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {'xclass': xclass, 'section':section},
                            datatype: 'json',
                            success: function (data) {
                                $("#resultlist").html(data);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }); //event.preventDefault(); 

            </script>
```

**My Controller**

```
public function fetchStudent($class,$section){
    $this->load->model('Admission_model');
    $data = $this->Admission_model->fetchStudentmodel($class,$section);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    exit();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**My Model is**

```
public function fetchStudentmodel($x,$y) {
    $uid = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $data = $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('student')
            ->where(['user_id' => $uid,'class'=>$x, 'section'=>$y])
            ->get();

    if ($data->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $data->result();
    } else {
        return 'No data Available';
    }
}
```

See this image then you can understand what I want to do [image]

Comment: Do you want to pass in the URL or as a POST value?

Comment: Sir, I want to pass two variable in Ajax URL 

like url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Admission/fetchStudent/"+ xclass,

Comment: u are only sending 1 param `data: {'xclass': xclass}` and u are not using this value in your controller as well, i think u are using slug from the url.

Comment: Sir I had also use  {'xclass':xclass, 'section':section} but i failed

Comment: try with `{xclass:xclass, section:section}`

Comment: Try to use AJAX Datatables to fetch the student data

Comment: What about `url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Admission/fetchStudent/" + $('.sclass').val() + "/" + $('.section').val();`? This should suit your current controller method signature.

                        //
                        $.ajax({

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you can pass 2 values in params as like:

```
data: { key1: value1, key2: value2 }
```

And you can get them in your controller by using `$_POST`

But in your example, you are sending only 1 param and not getting it in your controller, your are using your URL slug for getting class.

In your controller file, you can simple get the values in `$_POST`, you can check both values by using:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
```

You will get your both values in `$_POST` then you can access by using `$_POST['key1']` or `$_POST['key2']`

**One more thing,** i dont know why are you using single quote on your param's key, this will be converted in a string variable i think.

Second solution for your example is:
var xclass = $('.sclass').val();
var section = $('.section').val();

```
data: 'class='+xclass+'&section='+section, // here you can use quote and & for separation.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This,**

```
$.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Admission/fetchStudent/",
      type: "POST",
      data: ({xclass: xclass, section:section}),//changes
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
             $("#resultlist").html(data);
      }
 });
```

```
public function fetchStudent(){//changes
    $this->load->model('Admission_model');
    $class  = $this->input->post('xclass');//changes
    $section  = $this->input->post('section');//changes
    $data = $this->Admission_model->fetchStudentmodel($class,$section);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    exit();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: `$_POST('xclass')` this will create problem i think, check other answer.